# Raspberry Pi 4 becomes unresponsive after Chromium idle

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am building a kiosk application on my Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB RAM Version) that requires that Chromium continuously idles as a service. I created a supervisorctl service that will keep it alive and give me the ability to easily stop, start, fetch status, etc.

However, after some time I am noticing that the entire interface freezes. I had Chromium running in the background and 3 terminals in the foreground:

1. Terminal running `tail -f` of the service log
2. Terminal running `dmesg -w`
3. Terminal running `htop`

After my Pi idled for about 3 hours, sure enough the interface froze. The Pi was functional from an SSH perspective, I could run commands and do whatever I wanted but there was a severe crash from the interface side.

Looking at the terminals I had open for more information, here is what I got:

1. Terminal 1 provided no information.
2. Terminal 2 provided some information:

```
[ 8845.340649]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8845.340653] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8845.340658] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 8845.340680] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 8845.340698] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8845.340707] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 8845.340715] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 8845.340723] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 8845.340732] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 8845.340741] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8845.340747] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8845.340756] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 8845.340765] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 8845.340773] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 8845.340780] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 8845.340788] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 8845.340797] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8845.340805] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8845.340812] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8845.340819] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8845.340824] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 8845.340829] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340834] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340839] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 8845.340845] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8845.340849]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8845.340853] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8845.340857] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 8845.340873] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 8845.340885] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8845.340892] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 8845.340901] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 8845.340909] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 8845.340916] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 8845.340924] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 8845.340930] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8845.340937] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8845.340945] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 8845.340960] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8845.340967] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8845.340973] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8845.340979] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8845.340983] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 8845.340988] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340993] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340998] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 8968.221452] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8968.221459]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8968.221463] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8968.221468] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 8968.221490] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 8968.221513] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8968.221522] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 8968.221531] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 8968.221539] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 8968.221547] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 8968.221557] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8968.221564] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8968.221572] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 8968.221581] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 8968.221589] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 8968.221597] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 8968.221604] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 8968.221614] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8968.221623] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8968.221629] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8968.221637] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8968.221642] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 8968.221647] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221652] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221657] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 8968.221663] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8968.221668]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8968.221671] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8968.221675] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 8968.221692] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 8968.221704] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8968.221712] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 8968.221720] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 8968.221728] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 8968.221736] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 8968.221743] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 8968.221750] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8968.221757] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8968.221765] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 8968.221775] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8968.221782] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8968.221788] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8968.221794] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8968.221798] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 8968.221803] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221808] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221816] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9091.102268] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9091.102275]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9091.102279] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9091.102284] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 9091.102305] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 9091.102322] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9091.102330] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 9091.102339] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 9091.102347] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 9091.102356] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 9091.102364] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9091.102371] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9091.102379] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 9091.102387] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 9091.102395] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 9091.102403] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 9091.102411] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 9091.102420] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9091.102428] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9091.102435] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9091.102443] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9091.102447] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 9091.102452] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102458] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102463] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9091.102469] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9091.102473]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9091.102476] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9091.102480] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 9091.102497] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 9091.102508] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9091.102516] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 9091.102524] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 9091.102532] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 9091.102540] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 9091.102547] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 9091.102554] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9091.102561] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9091.102569] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 9091.102578] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9091.102585] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9091.102591] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9091.102597] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9091.102602] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 9091.102606] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102612] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102616] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9213.983078] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9213.983085]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9213.983089] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9213.983094] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 9213.983115] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 9213.983133] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9213.983141] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 9213.983150] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 9213.983157] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 9213.983166] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 9213.983174] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9213.983181] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9213.983190] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 9213.983199] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 9213.983207] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 9213.983215] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 9213.983222] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 9213.983232] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9213.983240] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9213.983247] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9213.983254] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9213.983259] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 9213.983264] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983270] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983274] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9213.983280] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9213.983285]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9213.983288] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9213.983292] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 9213.983309] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 9213.983320] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9213.983328] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 9213.983336] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 9213.983344] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 9213.983351] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 9213.983359] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 9213.983366] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9213.983373] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9213.983381] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 9213.983390] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9213.983397] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9213.983404] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9213.983410] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9213.983414] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 9213.983419] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983424] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983429] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9336.863894] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9336.863900]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9336.863904] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9336.863909] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 9336.863931] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 9336.863947] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9336.863956] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 9336.863964] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 9336.863972] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 9336.863981] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 9336.863989] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9336.863996] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9336.864015] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 9336.864023] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 9336.864031] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 9336.864038] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 9336.864046] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 9336.864055] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9336.864064] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9336.864070] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9336.864077] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9336.864082] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 9336.864087] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864092] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864097] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9336.864103] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9336.864107]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9336.864111] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9336.864115] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 9336.864132] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 9336.864143] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9336.864151] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 9336.864159] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 9336.864166] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 9336.864174] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 9336.864182] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 9336.864188] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9336.864195] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9336.864203] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 9336.864213] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9336.864220] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9336.864226] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9336.864232] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9336.864237] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 9336.864241] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864247] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864252] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
```

3. Terminal 3 appeared to show a healthy device:
   [htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lduj3.png)

Additionally, I tried to do a `sudo service lightdm restart`, but the terminal just hung and did not do anything. See sys-log below:

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 576 (lightdm) with signal SIGKILL.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 702 (Xorg) with signal SIGKILL.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1232 (openbox) with signal SIGKILL.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user pi.
```

After this failed, I did a `sudo reboot now` and the system never rebooted. I had to unplug and plug the device back in.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on here? What could be causing this issue?

For your reference, please see output of os-release below:

```
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Answer (score 1):

I was creating a similar application just running chrome via autostart script /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

@chromium-browser file:///home/pi/fire.html --start-fullscreen

It crashes in a very similar manner...

It seems the only fix I can suggest is to wait for someone to find this bug and issue a fix and post it here. I don't have reputation sufficient to comment or I would just make this a comment.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail -f /var/log/messages
Jan  5 11:03:31 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.346382] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Jan  5 11:03:31 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.346425] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
Jan  5 11:03:31 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.346535] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
Jan  5 11:03:32 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.873730] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jan  5 11:03:32 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.873736] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jan  5 11:03:32 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.873746] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jan  5 11:03:32 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.027721] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jan  5 11:03:32 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.027739] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jan  5 11:03:32 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.027758] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Jan  5 11:05:36 raspberrypi kernel: [  106.311197] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1025.0004: HID++ 1.0 device connected.
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068199] kworker/2:2     D    0  2383      2 0x00000000
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068241] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068285] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068306] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068327] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068347] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068369] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068390] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068407] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068428] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf5d90c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068473] [<bf5d90c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068491] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068508] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068525] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068536] Exception stack(0xd8223fb0 to 0xd8223ff8)
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068549] 3fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068562] 3fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Jan  5 14:12:13 raspberrypi kernel: [11303.068574] 3fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
Jan  5 14:14:16 raspberrypi kernel: [11425.950256] kworker/2:2     D    0  2383      2 0x00000000
```

Comment: Good to know it's not just me. I downloaded firefox-esr and it looks like it is not crashing with that browser. You may want to try and use your web app with the firefox-esr application and Modern Kiosk Firefox extension. Please let me know what results you see with Firefox if you decide to try it!

Comment: I will try Firefox. Interesting to note is the problem only occurs for me when loading a local html file via file:// type url. I posted my test files here if anyone wants to download and reproduce. Http://poleguy.com/raspberry_fire/fire.html